# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.location.href = '/charCreate'')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Good evening!

I am creating a React app in which the user can navigate between different pages such as Login, Register, Create Character, etc. This app is both for web and Android. While in the web app, this redirect looks completely fine and loads the CharCreate.js file properly, the Android app does not, and I receive an Unhandled promise rejection.

I am aware that I need to route the page differently on Android, including changing the import from react-router-dom to react-router-native, but I continue to receive this warning. I cannot proceed with development without it going away.

Here is my App.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Router, Routes, NativeRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-native";
import { render } from "react-dom";
//import Register from "./frontend/Register.js";
import CharCreate from "./frontend/CharCreate.js";
//import QuestForm from "./frontend/components/QuestPage";
import Login from "./frontend/Login.js";
import Auth from "./frontend/auth.js";
import 'localstorage-polyfill';

export default function App() {

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
  console.log(token);
    // true == active user (logged in)
    const [state, setState] = useState(token !== null && token !== "" ? true : false);

    // Set user vars to access the Canvas page
    function onLogin(active)
    {
        setState(active);
        return <Redirect to="/charCreate"/>
    }

    // clear all fields on logout
    function onLogout(active)
    {
        setState(active);
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

    function getUser(token) {

    }

    return (
      <NativeRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path="/charCreate" element={<CharCreate/>}/>
            <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth/>}/>
          </Routes>
      </NativeRouter>
  );
    
}
```

And the following is the button that should redirect from the initial Login.js to CharCreate.js:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => (window.location.href = './charCreate')} style={styles.registerMe}>
```

Any advice would be much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in react native, we don't have window location and it's undefined. you can see what we have in the window object with

```
console.log(Object.keys(window))
```

instead of window.location I prefer to use useHistory hook like that
check this link
[useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/Hooks/usehistory)